# Build application on docker

Tags: java, spring, docker

I build web application and service to docker from tomcat directory, in web application application.properties file I specify service url with port 8886 but when i use web call to api the application is calling on port 886. Please help me!![image: ![![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGdJd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJJEe.png)]

I tried changing other ports, changing environment variable name but same result

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]. We would need a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.